# How do I define an external asset as an icon for the "AndroidInitializationSettings" in flutter_local_notifications?

Tags: plugins, assets, flutter-local-notification

I want to create a standalone library for handling notifications. The goal is to have a library I can use through various Flutter apps. While creating libraries containing different packages from https://pub.dev/ before worked fine, I'm now struggeling with the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin. To initialize the plugin you need to define `InitializationSettings()` containing platformspecific settings like `AndroidInitializationSettings()` or `DarwinInitializationSettings()`. The `AndroidInitializationSettings()` needs a string defining an app icon that is displayed at the notification. I know that you can name an asset from `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` for example. But if I'm writing a library I don't have any `android` folder or other assets inside my project.

Does someone has an idea if there is a workaround for this? Is there any possibility to use an external asset for `AndroidInitializationSettings()`?